# navigation either being clipped with overflow:hidden or wrapping without it

Tags: html, css, navigation, overflow

So I am having issues with my navigation for a website I am working on. I want the navigation to have a set height, but i want to have drop down menues as well. I have tried everything over the past 9 hours to get this working to no avail.

I need the navigation to not wrap like shown here:
http://jsfiddle.net/88fYK/482/

CSS:

```
.top_nav {
    background-image: url('images/navbg.gif');white-space:nowrap;
    height:32px;
    }

.top_nav #menu{
height:32px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.top_nav #menu ul{
float:left;
padding:0;
margin:0;
line-height:30px;

}
.top_nav #menu li{
position:relative;
float:left;
list-style:none;
background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
border-radius:5px;
}
.top_nav #menu ul li ul{
position:absolute;
display:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
top:30px;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.top_nav #menu ul li a{
text-align:center;
font:"Arial Black", Arial;
font-size:24px;
color:rgba(255,255,255,9);
width:150px;
height:30px;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;

}
.top_nav #menu ul li:hover{
background-color:rgba(128,128,128,1);
text-decoration:none;
}
.top_nav #menu ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
z-index:1;
}
.top_nav #menu ul li:hover ul li a{
background:rgba(0,0,0,9);
z-index:1;
border-bottom:1px solid rgba(160,160,164,1);
opacity:0.9;
text-decoration:none;
border-radius:5px;
}
.top_nav #menu ul li ul li:hover{
background:rgba(128,128,128,1);
opacity:0.8;
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="top_nav">
<div id="menu">

<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Video</a>    <!--This is in main menu-->
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>    <!--This is in drop downmenu-->
<li><a href="#">Tutorial</a></li>     <!--This is in drop downmenu-->
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">link</a><ul> 
<li><a href="#">sub</a></li>    <!--This is in drop downmenu-->
<li><a href="#">sub</a></li>     <!--This is in drop downmenu-->
</ul></li> 
<li><a href="#">link</a><ul> 
<li><a href="#">sub</a></li>    <!--This is in drop downmenu-->
<li><a href="#">sub</a></li>     <!--This is in drop downmenu-->
</ul></li> 
<li><a href="#">link</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">link</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">link</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">link</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">link</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">link</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">link</a></li> 

</ul></div></div>
```

But i need the drop down menues to work like shown here:
http://jsfiddle.net/88fYK/484/
(same with removal of a 'overflow:hidden;')

The main main issue are:
either the navigation wraps (I cannot have this)
Or the dropdown menus do not work (i need them to)

I need to somehow "ignore" any links that would make the navigation wrap. I've tried every float, position, clearfix out there and i cannot seem to get anything to work.

any help given is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Congratulations you have fixed it. Sometimes trying some online menu maker tool is also a good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, all I did was added

```
.top_nav #menu>ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and removed a couple of floats.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xaqzvevf/

PS: That CSS declaration selects all `li` elements where the parent is a `ul` where the parent is `#menu`.

Comment: Awesome! I was getting myself in a mess, forgeting what was where and what i still needed =). With a little editing from yours i got a semi desired output from here: http://jsfiddle.net/xaqzvevf/1/ i can play around with it a bit later to fully cut off anything that doesnt "fit", but for now this will do. thanks again for the help.